# B Phase Power Outage

Tags: electrical

What is the corrective measure when B Phase of load center is not providing power.  Does the entire circuit breaker panel have to be replaced?

Thanks!

Comment: Sure, in the sense that replacing a car computer is a very expensive way to reset a car computer. I think more troubleshooting is called for. Can you provide more information?

Comment: Are both phases from the utility providing power?  Is your main shutoff breaker passing power to both legs of the panel?

Comment: The most likely cause is at the pole. Call the power company.

Comment: Do you have all three phases present at the feed lugs? I'd check for voltage there as a first stop....

Comment: Where are you is this 3 phase power or split phase (U.S. type power), in the US split phase is commonly referred to as legs A leg and B leg as they are on the same phase, as @jim Stewart suspected the problem is usually from the power company but can be the main breaker or connections to the breaker/ buss. Where you are at would help , if in the U.S. contact your power company, and tell them you have lost a leg, they usually fix these things quickly as they can cause all kinds of problems.